# trim sorted array

Tags: php, arrays, trim

final question for today... I've gotten far (thanks to all of you!), but i need to go even further.. I got a sorted array, and i need to have the upper highest values, so the i need to trim all the lower values under the highest...

```
value  key
Boerée 5
Bour 5
Linszen 4
de Wilde 3
Dingemans 3
Koelman 3
Tijssen 1
van der Meer 1
Bakker 1
de Haan 1
van Tricht 1
Nieman 1
Boer 1
```

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by trim lower values?

Comment: I have NO idea what you are talking about. Please post a var_dump of an example array, and further define 'upper highest values' and 'lower under [the] highest'

Comment: I am not sure I understood the input : how can you have several values for each keys?

Comment: Do you mean you want the array to contain only the entries with the highest value (in this case, Boerée/5 and Bour/5?)

Comment: By the way, as Mathias E. was hinting at already, your left column probably contains keys and your right columns contains values, instead of the other way around...

Comment: "Do you mean you want the array to contain only the entries with the highest value (in this case, Boerée/5 and Bour/5?)" Yes thats what i mean!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sorted so you just make a loop for the amount of results that you want? Smells like homework so I'm not gonna post a full example. (Think I posted to much already).

```
$amount = 5;
for($i = 0; $i < amount; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks, i need to get max value of my array, $amount = max($authors); and then the rest! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this should work, assuming I understand what you mean. I just felt like writing it too much to wait for your answer :)

```
function onlyTheStrong($array) {
    $returnArray = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($max) || $value > $max) {
            $max = $value;
            $returnArray = array($key => $value);
        } else if ($value == $max) {
            $returnArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $returnArray;
}
```

It works for an unsorted array as well.

EDIT:

How about that, you can just use:

```
$top_authors = array_keys($authors, max($authors));
```

Comment: Thanks but already wrote this and it works: $biggest_amount = max($authors);
$top_authors = array();

foreach ($authors as $lastn => $key)
{
if ($biggest_amount == $key)
{
$top_authors[$lastn] +=1;
}

}

Comment: Hey, I found a quicker way: `$top_authors = array_keys($authors, max($authors));`!